# Android: change marker's size/color based on parameter

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

Currently I'm using google-map-API V2 for android google map,is there any way I can based on one variable parameter change the marker(pin) size/color of google map?

Answer (score 0):

```
float valueBetween0and360 = 222.222;
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(valueBetween0and360));
```

will change marker icon color.

For size you will have to provide your own icons and use [`BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#fromResource%28int%29).