# Make Google Maps API Default Marker Smaller

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, mapfragment

Im using Google Maps API in my app and placing a lot of markers on the map.
**I need to make the size of the markers smaller**, so they won't cover the whole country.

Note that **i gotta use the default marker** `BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker`
because i wrote an algo that defines the color of each marker group.

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT:
I know there is a way to resize the marker by setting a custom Marker image,
But i need to use the defualt marker,**Therefore this topic is NOT duplicate**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change marker size in Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851641/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-api-v2)

Comment: Not a dup man,i have to use the BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker so i cant use the solutions mentioned there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41513350/9025311

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822504/android-change-markers-size-color-based-on-parameter

Comment: I edited my question to explain why this is not a duplicate .

Answer (score 0):

Follow these two steps down here:

1. Replace the Default Google Map Marker with the Bitmap icon as explained  [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker)
2. Then resize the particular Bitmap Icon in Activity as shown [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32187898/7098524)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but that way if i want to have 7 different marker colors, i need to get 7 Bitmap icons in a different color? @eLi

Comment: You may do it in that way as you think OR you may use activity class in changing one Bitmap Icon color form another